# Problema ao criar ProfileCommon

Tags: asp.net, webforms, asp.net-profile

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Estou com o seguinte problema ao criar o meu perfil, alguém pode me ajudar no que pode estar acontecendo?

Meu web Config está configurado da seguinte forma.

```
<profile defaultProvider="AspNetSqlProfileProvider">
  <providers>
    <clear />
    <add name="AspNetSqlProfileProvider" type="System.Web.Profile.SqlProfileProvider" applicationName="/Usuarios" connectionStringName="labPuc" />
  </providers>
  <properties>
    <add name="UserId" type="System.Guid" />
    <add name="Nome" type="System.String" />
    <add name="TipoPermissao" type="System.String" />
    <add name="Email" type="System.String" />
    <add name="Habilitado" type="System.String" />
  </properties>
</profile>
```

Answer (score 1):

Esse código não funcionaria nunca. Aqui você sobrescreve o `perfil` montado via Linq:

```
perfil = (ProfileCommon) Create(userName, true);
```

O certo seria manter só a sentença Linq. Essa linha que destaquei pode ser retirada.

Comment: Mais quando vou obter o perfil ele vem vazio. ProfileCommon perfil = (ProfileCommon)HttpContext.Current.Profile; Alias dá o mesmo erro.

Comment: Pelo que percebi meu Context e meu userName e as outras propriedades vem vazias. Será que tem algo haver?

Comment: Como já te disse, você precisa devolver um `ProfileCommon` preenchido com as propriedades desejadas. Ou você mantém o Linq e devolve o objeto montado por ele, omitindo a linha que coloquei na resposta, ou você preenche um objeto pelo Linq, chama a linha e altera o objeto da linha com o retorno do Linq.

Comment: Essa pergunta merece está aqui @Cigano? 2 anos e só 25 acessos!:)

Comment: Eu acho a pergunta excelente. Pena que a abordagem de Profiles é pouco explorada.